# Swap Azure Web site slots with Publish profile

Tags: azure-web-app-service, publish-profiles, azure-cli

Folks, I am wondering if there are any ways to swap a staging slot with production when I only have the publish profile for the web site.

I am aware that I can swap slots with Azure CmdLet but that requires adding the Azure subscription into Powershell CLI. In my case, Infrastructure team provisions the web sites in a subscription and provides the Publish Profiles to the Dev team for deployments. The idea we have is dev team will deploy (MSDeploy we are using) the site first in a staging slot and run some sanity check and finally swap the slot. In order to swap the Dev team needs to have the access to the entire Azure Subscription. Which is not what I want. Apparently we are using "Auto Swap" option to do the swap. But this doesn't give the dev team enough control to abandon a bad staging deployment.

Is it possible at all to do the swap for the dev team, given that they only have the publish profiles for the web sites? I would appreciate thoughts, pointers, insights, suggestions etc.

Comment: Anybody can give me some pointers, please..?

Comment: Could you use auto swap feature? Your IT team can configure Auto swap with the defined staging slot. Check out this tutorial. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/#configure-auto-swap-for-your-web-app

Comment: Thank you @GandhaliSamant for replying on this. AutoSwap is a nice option but didn't fit my requirement, as I wanted to run an Acceptance test on deployment slot before swapping the slots.